# How can I make other empires like me enough to join an alliance?

Tags: stellaris

I know that much of the initial scoring is based on the traits (Xenophobes don't like anyone, certain traits rub other traits the wrong way), but what actions can I take to positively influence potential allies?

Many of the options available to me are mood killers, and are great for cajoling them into being hostile enough for open warfare (including just *existing* near their borders). By comparison I just don't seem to have the have the tools to push an empire those last few points towards accepting an alliance; I can only make so many lopsided trade agreements before it bleeds my coffers dry (and I'm not sure multiple such trades have much effect), and I have a limited number of embassies to spread around.

[image]

(This is not the empire that's only a few points away; that empire got snatched up by another alliance, and their 'acceptance rating' now has a -1000 attached to it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there are different methods of increasing relations with other empires:

- **Establish an embassy**: you can establish an embassy with the other empire in the same screen as the screen shot you provided. This will increase relations slowly until it reaches 100. You have a limit of 3 embassy by default but government type options can allow you extras.
- **Rival the same empire**: If the other empire has a rival, rivaling that empire will boost your relations by 25 <sup>(1)</sup>; this only lasts for the duration of the rivalry.
- **Select xenophile traits**: being a xenophile will increase other empire relations by 10, or by 20 if fanatic xenophile.

---

(1) [Diplomacy - Stellaris Wiki](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Diplomacy&oldid=7532): Opinion modifiers » Mutual rivals (17 May 2016)

Comment: Can you still establish an embassy?  I don't remember seeing this option.

Comment: @nick - It's been a while since I've played but it wouldn't surprise me if they have locked it behind some kind of tech, it was a little OP being able to send an embassy to anyone instantly. Will open it tonight and check.

Comment: Embassies are not a thing anymore.

Answer (score 5):

S.Wessels's answer hits several points, but note also the "relative power of empires" modifier. Other empires will be much more willing to enter in an alliance with you if you're stronger than them.

If you Guarantee the Independence of another empire, that will put you on the hook for some defensive wars involving them, but will boost your relations by 25. (You can make this less of a strategic loss by going for a mutual guarantee of independence, which is sort of like a defensive alliance.)

Answer (score -2):

I always go and guaranty independence then immediately and after that I offer a really lopsided trade deal it confuses the new ia and gives you  10 extra opinion points then you would normal get but this only lasts for 2 game months