# How to overcome 'Differing war philosophy' to create an alliance in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

The Empire found a true friend, the trade is good, Science is exchanged, dependency is guarantied and all the rest.

Our governor wish to create an alliance with them - all is good beside 'Differing war philosophy' which is the only obstacle.

How can our government change policy accordingly, to overcome this last obstacle?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265580/how-can-i-make-other-empires-like-me-enough-to-join-an-alliance?rq=1

Comment: If you list all the current relationship modifiers, it would probably be easier to suggest a course of action.

Comment: @DCShannon: Thanks for the good will, but the conversation is if and how can the empires overcome this conflict.

Comment: Did you post the wrong screenshot? There's no "differing war philosophy" there. The general answer is "raise their opinion in other ways". If that's all you want, then this is a duplicate of the question I linked that describes general ways to improve opinion. If you want to know what you should do in your specific situation, then that's another question, which is how I was interpreting this.

Comment: The second screenshot is the Alliance acceptance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get rid of the differing war philosophy penalty, because that is based on your empire ethics. Instead, you need to get enough bonuses to offset the penalty.

I'd have to do some testing to ensure that this is the case, but here are some things that I *believe* would help:

- Increase their opinion of you. You're already getting a +21 bonus. There should still be some levels higher than that, though.
- Some things, like a Non-Aggression Pact, will help not only your opinion, but give a direct buff to the Alliance negotiations. I think Migration Access may help in this way as well. You may not be able to get migration access, depending on your mutual ethics, but one-way is probably better than neither.
- You don't appear to be trading with the empire. Trading improves their opinion of you by +5, and *may* directly impact the alliance negotiations. I often just trade a few minerals a month for a few energy a month.
- Common rivals improve relations. Determine who their rival is from the Empire Contacts screen, and declare the same rival.
- Common threats improve relations. If they're at war with somebody, go to war with them as well.
- If you become significantly more powerful, you can increase the "relative power of empires" modifier.

Answer (score 0):

War philosophy is depending on your empires' population ethos.

Pacifist will not like Militarist. Vice versa.

I am not aware of how the mechanic that determines your governing ethos get changed if you replace all of your population that support a different philosophy.

Comment: I've had this come up despite not having a stance on Pacifist vs Militarist, so it seems possible that you can have this even if you're neutral.

Comment: It was mainly used as an example. I am not aware of all interrelationship between all possible ethos. For example: Spiritualist vs Materialist could introduce this interrelationship. Given all possible ethos and what not. It can be difficult to from one glance determine the source of the difference war philosophy.

Comment: So, no way to make the final step toward alliance? The relationship is missing only (-15) points.

Comment: There are various way to boost your relationship such as having mutual rival and giving them favorable trades.

Comment: @Vyndicu: Did most of that (didn't meet their rival yet).

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what else to do. Except keep looking for the rival and discovery them so you can use that. Also even if they won't accept alliance. It is much easier to get civilian access so your science ship can go to their rival. If access is a problem that is.

Answer (score -2):

I think the "different war philosophy" is about when you can declare war: just for defense, to recapture you planets, or free war, and you can change it on the Government menu, on the top/left of the screen, on the 3º screen there.

http://www.stellariswiki.com/Policies